# Meaning of (e, v) => in c# and Changed Property as Parameter

Tags: c#

What does `(e, v) =>` syntactically mean in C#?

e.g.,

```
TreeViewModel root = TreeViewModel.initializeRoot(parentStatus, statuses);
root.PropertyChanged += (e, v) => updateConditions();
```

I know that I'm registering to listen to property changes of the root object. And, if such an event happens, then I'm calling the `updateConditions()` method. But, what is the `(e, v) =>` in between?

And, is there are way to send the changed property as a parameter to `updateConditions()`?

Comment: It's [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Please follow MSDN documentation for this question [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: The entire `(e, v) => updateConditions();` is a lambda expression returning a `void` when supplied two parameters.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Dup: check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your second question:

It is possible to send updated `PropertyName` into `updateConditions()`. Because `v` is of type `PropertyChangedEventArgs` it has `PropertyName` property:

```
root.PropertyChanged += (e, v) => updateConditions(v.PropertyName);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the second question that most people (including myself) neglected

Answer (score 6):

It's a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Basically it creates an anonymous method which calls `updateConditions()` and binds the event to that anonymous method.

It's equivalent to.

```
private void root_PropertyChanged(object e, PropertyChangeEventArgs v)
{
    updateConditions();
}

root.PropertyChanged += root_PropertyChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `(e, v) => (some sort of expression)` creates a lambda function taking parameters 'e' and 'v' and then returning the result of evaluating the expression. It's basically a way of creating a function in place, so you don't have to define a delegate and pass one in that way. In your case, it takes the arguments e and v and then simply returns the result of calling `updateConditions()`. Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24255/Exploring-Lambda-Expression-in-C for more detail on how these are used.